# export via mongoose streams to node-csv

Tags: node.js, mongoose

trying to get a CSV dump of some data (~500Mb) in mongodb. Thought streams would be the way to go, to avoid building up an array in memory and then building the csv at once.

But, it seems the stream that mongoose creates and the one that csv expects are not the same thing.

```
 var stream = Subscriber.find().stream()                                                                                                   
 stream.setEncoding = function() { }                                                                                                       


 csv().from.stream(stream).on('record', function(record, index) {                                                                          
     console.log(record)                                                                                                                   
     console.log(index)                                                                                                                    
 })
```

without the `setEncoding()` stub above, I get an error about that when csv calls setEncoding on the stream. With it, results in

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'
    at [object Object].stringify   (/home/project/node_modules/csv/lib/stringifier.js:98:35)
```

So, is this even the right approach? if so, what is the problem with the streams?

Comment: do you want to do this in node? Because you could use [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/#collection-import-with-mongoimport) for dumping csv into mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

As zeMirco said: to get a CSV dump of a collection, I'd use the `mongoexport` tool that comes with MongoDB. Here's an example of exporting a collection called "users" in a database "mydatabase" to CSV format:

```
$ mongoexport --csv --host localhost:27017 --db mydatabase --collection users --fields name,email,age -o output.csv
```

And you'll get something that looks like this:

```
$ cat output.csv
name,email,age
renold,renold.ronaldson@gmail.com,21
jacob,xXxjacobxXx@hotmail.com,16
```

Comment: good idea, but we need to do counts, date parsing, aggregations and such on each returned document, i.e., transformations. AFAIK `mongoexport` can't do that

Comment: You could export everything as JSON using the `--json` flag, load it in Node to do your processing, then write it out again as CSV with [json2csv](https://npmjs.org/package/json2csv). Or you could just create a new collection with the processed documents through node, and then export that. Or maybe you could use MapReduce, if that fits in with your processing style.

Comment: "create a new collection with the processed documents through node" - interesting workaround, might try that. Actually the problem isn't creating a CSV, I can do that with `node-csv` and it works with small datasets which is what we have so far. But was wondering why the mongoose model `stream()` doesn't work with with `csv().from.stream()`, because streams seemed like the way to go for bigger data (maybe not the case, and prob should break up the csv anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Replace `process.stdout` with a filestream to write it to a file.

```
var csv = require('csv')
var through = require('through')
var Model = require('...')
_ = require('underscore')

var modelStream = Model.find().stream();

modelStream.pipe(through(write, end)).pipe(csv()).pipe(process.stdout);

function end(){ console.log('done'); }
function write(doc) {
    this.queue(_.values(doc.toObject({getters:true, virtuals:false})));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the csv from a webserver by accessing a URL and your using express you can do this:

```
var through = require('through');
var csv = require('csv')
var MyModel = require('./my_model');

app.get('/download_csv/', function(req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=attendances.csv');
    res.contentType('csv');
    res.write('property 1,property 2\n');

    var modelStream = MyModel.find().stream();

    modelStream.
        pipe(through(write, end)).
        pipe(csv.stringify()).
        pipe(res);

    function end() {
        res.end();
        console.log('done outputting file');
    }

    function write(doc) {
        var myObject = doc.toObject({getters:true, virtuals:false});
        this.queue([
            myObject.property_1,
            myObject.property_2
        ]);
    }
});
```

NOTE: This is using the latest version of the csv module (v0.4) whereas the previous answers are using an older version of the module.